# Create random responsive circles in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am working on a project on which I need to create circles at random places with different radius and I want that design to be responsive as well. I am attaching the output that I need but I am unable to achieve that.

[image]

Comment: Nope... Not yet

Comment: might be MeadiaQuery can help you..